# is there something missing in my php code

Tags: php, upload

Hi i am quite new to web developing, i am creating a website for our local pool league, and have found some code to use for people to upload pictures to the gallery on the website, but i cannot get it to work, and am very basic with .php, when i try to upload an image i get this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in   /home/u727445903/public_html/upload_file.php on line 5

here is the code for the upload.php

```
<?php
$folder = “/public_html/images/gallery”;
if (is_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))  {  
    if (move_uploaded_file($HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],     $folder.$HTTP_POST_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
         Echo “File uploaded”;
    } else {
         Echo “File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions”;
    };
} else {
     Echo “File is not uploaded.”;
};
?>
```

Any help would gratefully accepted

Comment: Don't use funny quotes: `“` . Use regular quotes: `"`

Comment: Funkyyyy `“ ... ”` - do `" ... "`

Comment: @JohnConde *Plus* `”` ;)

Comment: Don't use MS Word for development.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I was just going to edit my comment in regards to that.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It's more likely the site he copy/pasted from contained the curly quotes.

Comment: Use extreme caution when copy/pasting code from the web, as many CMS systems insist on replacing plain double-quotes with the fancy kind. Also, if this code was created in a word processor of some kind, that could be a cause. Use a plain text editor intended for coding.

Comment: thanks for the help there, got that sorted now, apart from its now just saying 'file is not uploaded'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have book or "curly" style quotes in your code (`“”`). The compiler has no idea what to do with those.

Change them to straight quotes (`""`).

Comment: Brilliant what a speedy response, thanks guys going to try that now, thank you